# Guardian If concept

Tags: logic

I was talking with a friend, who is also an programmer (but he's a senior programmer, working on a huge IT company), and he was talking about good practices in programing, and he said that is somewhat of a trend, that some developers are trying to not use an "if else" logic, but instead using an "Guardian if" concept, which eliminates the need for the else.. I've searched for this concept, but i actually found no results anywhere, so I was wondering if someone here is familiar with this concept, and would care to explain it.

PS: if this is not the right place to ask this question, i do apologise, and i'll delete the question.

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1074100.1074433#:~:text=The%20term%20guarded%20command%2C%20as,execution%20is%20controlled%20by%20B. In other words, not exactly a new idea :-)

Comment: hmmm i see, so it's not "guardian" but "guarded" also hahah, thank you for the link, i will read it and now that i have the correct name, will read more on it!! thanks!!